# What does 'relocation' mean?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am reading about `Base & Bounds` memory protection mechanism, and I noticed the use of the term *'relocation'* in the context of `address space`, but failed to understand the meaning associated with it.

Below are some examples:

1. U.C Berkeley L02/CS162:

   > relocating loader

   [image]
2. [Wisconsin S15/CS537](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bart/537/lecturenotes/s15.html)

   > Each process appears to have a completely private memory of size equal
   >   to the bounds register plus 1. Processes are protected from each
   >   other. No address relocation is necessary when a process is loaded.

Furthermore, I searched for the term and found only [the definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) that wasn't very clear to me.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Relocation* means moving stuff from one place to another. In your case, there is a program which contains some absolute addresses, which make sense if the program is located at a certain address A. If the program is loaded to a different address B, we need to update all of these addresses, translating them by B−A. This is *address relocation*. A loader (a program loading another program to memory) which does this is called a *relocating loader*.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what do you mean by "for one place to another", as well as "the problem".

Comment: Thanks for the update. In which case the program gets loaded to a different address B? Are you referring to another process?

Comment: The answer depends in principle on the operating system. I imagine that in modern OSs, this is always the case. Maybe DOS was different.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what do you mean. Are A and B two different programs?

Comment: No, just two different addresses. The program doesn't know in advance where it would be loaded, that is, B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71608/discussion-between-kais-and-yuval-filmus).